# Why are my PNG files Crashing my python pptx files?

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

Simple problem; hard fix. I'm trying to make a Python .pptx. Whenever I use generic PowerPoint templates, the code works. Whenever I reference a slide from a slide template, my presentation crashes and deletes. Why does this happen?

This code works.

```
from pptx import Presentation 
from pptx.util import Inches

img_path = 'monty-truth.png'

prs = Presentation() 
blank_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[6] 
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(blank_slide_layout)

left = top = Inches(1)
pic = slide.shapes.add_picture(img_path, left, top) 
prs.save('test.pptx')
```

This code does not work.

```
from pptx import Presentation 
from pptx.util import Inches

prs = Presentation('End_of_Programme Report Master DRAFT.pptx')

# Title
title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[0]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout)
title = slide.shapes.title
title.text = coursename

img_path = 'path.png'
prs = Presentation() 
blank_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[6] 
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(blank_slide_layout)

left = top = Inches(1)
pic = slide.shapes.add_picture(img_path, left, top) 
prs.save('test.pptx')
```

Comment: What does "crashes and deletes" mean specifically? Please post the traceback in its entirety.

Answer (score 1):

Since not all slides have title placeholder, you should verify that `slide.shapes.title` is not None.